# show input type=date without the year using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm working on a vanilla js code, in which the user can enter only a day and a month in the format of: "input type=date" (dd/mm) without the year. is there any way to acheive that without using jquery and date-picker?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the year later, but that's a bit messy. I would use two select elements instead of the input because that's probably the cleanest method

Answer (score -1):

get data

```
 var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDate();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp

get mouth

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: The question is not about getting parts of the current system date, but about having the user _input_ those parts via the frontend UI.

Comment: I was expecting you to reference n value and make your own history collector.